# Accessing db connection string within jsp using spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring

I am using a properties file to access database connection with Spring App Context like so :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
```

I want to now reference that the same string in my jsp, I tried this but no luck :

```
<c:out value="${app.jdbc.url}" />
```

?

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC? If so you could get the url in your Controller code and make it available as a property on your Model which you expose to your JSP at render time.

Comment: I am, and can happily add attributes to the model ... but what do I reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it this way :

```
@Autowired
private ComboPooledDataSource dataSource;
```

then in my controller method that returns view name:

```
model.addAttribute("db", dataSource.getJdbcUrl());
```

and in jsp simply referenced like this:

```
DB connection string is ${db}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Spring 3.x you can do something like:

```
@Value("#{'${app.jdbc.url}'}")
public void setURL(String url) { ... }
```

on your controller. You can then provide a getter for that property and access it from your JSP.

Also, I completely missed the Spring 3.1 part of your question. You could Autowire the Environment into your Controller. Then you can do:

```
environment.getProperty("app.jdbc.url")
```

Comment: when would setUrl() be called ? And by what ? And youa re suggesting having instance/thread specific vars then ?

Comment: It would be set by the framework assuming that you're Autowiring your controllers dependencies.

Comment: Field or property 'app' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'

Comment: I'm trying to confirm that it works for me. My laptop is playing up!

Comment: Edited the answer. Have confirmed that the new expression works for me.