# Spring Java config: import properties file

Tags: spring

How to import a properties file and access a property while using Java configuration to configure Spring.

I want to do all in java. Is there a way to do it?

I tried to use `@ImportResource("classpath:config.properties")` but did not work.

Comment: @ImportResource is for Spring beans, not properties files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've done this on my `@Configuration` class using:

```
@PropertySource(value="classpath:application.properties")
```

You can get the properties in number a number of ways:

1. Inject `Environment` into configuration beans that need the properties and use `environment.getProperty("my.property.value")`, or
2. Annotate a property with `@Value` as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602115/accessing-db-connection-string-within-jsp-using-spring-3-1/8602326#8602326).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works with spring 3.1